# How to downsample all the videos in a folder using ffmeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path, operating-system

I have a folder with videos of different types (mainly .MTS or .mov, but strong possibility that in future there will be other types). I want to downsample it. This is the code that I won't, but it's not working.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess, os
import cv2

path= '/Volumes/Element/videos/'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".MTS") or filename.endswith(".mp4"): 
        os.system("ffmpeg -i{0} -vf scale=500:-2 output%p.MTS".format(filename))
        continue
    else:
       os.system("ffmpeg -i{0} -vf scale=500:-2 output%p.MTS".format(filename))
       continue
```

Comment: *"it's not working"*. You should always include the actual errors instead of only saying it is not working.

Comment: @llogan there is no error.The output of the print(os.system(..)) command shows 256.So, I that might be the problem.Do you know how to approach the problem (regardless of the code that I wrote)

Comment: I don't know what 256 means, but you should determine if the problem is with the ffmpeg commands or the python code or both. You can add the `-report` option and ffmpeg will make a log file in the working directory so you can determine if ffmpeg is even executing.